# Scala: How to group every nth element of sub lists?

Tags: scala

Consider having this:
   `List(List("a1", "b1"), List("a2", "b2"))`

and I want this
 `List(List("a1", "a2"), List("b1", "b2"))`

I am pretty sure there is a functional way to do this.
But I have no idea how to solve.

Comment: It's in the standard library: `List(List("a1", "b1"), List("a2", "b2")).transpose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function like following should help with it.

```
  def transponent[T](l: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] = 
    if (l.head.isEmpty) Nil else l.map(_.head) :: transponent(l.map{_.tail})
```

Should probably be rewritten with @tailrecurtion.

Comment: Ok, basically it's a duplicate ... just found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683312/is-there-a-safe-way-in-scala-to-transpose-a-list-of-unequal-length-lists