# In Scala how to group elements in list with reverse dimension?

Tags: scala, list

Given:

```
scala> val a = (1 to 8).toList.grouped(3).toList
a: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8))
```

How to reverse dimension and group elements in `a` in this way:

```
List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this method, find out the length of the longest List and then collect elements from each sub list while looping through the indices:

```
val maxLength = a.map(_.length).max
// maxLength: Int = 3

(0 until maxLength) map (i => a flatMap (List(i) collect _))
// res45: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[List[Int]] = 
//        Vector(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want [transpose](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.1/#scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate) method, but official **transpoes** method doesn't support **unequal length** of sublist. maybe you want to try:

[Is there a safe way in Scala to transpose a List of unequal-length Lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683312/is-there-a-safe-way-in-scala-to-transpose-a-list-of-unequal-length-lists)

Answer (score 2):

Should use the groupBy method to group elements in the list. In your example, you are grouping every third element. In my solution, I am using the modulus operator to group every third element in the list:

```
val a = (1 to 8).toList.groupBy(_ % 3).values.toList
a: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 5, 8), List(1, 4, 7), List(3, 6))
```

If you want the results sorted (as in your example) then add the sortBy() at the end:

```
val a = (1 to 8).toList.groupBy(_ % 3).values.toList.sortBy(_(0))
a: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6))
```