# Scala - Combine two lists in an alternating fashion

Tags: list, scala

How do I merge 2 lists in such a way that the resulting list contains the elements of 2 lists in alternating fashion in Scala.

**Input:**

```
val list1 = List("Mary", "a", "lamb")

val list2 = List("had", "little")
```

**Output:**

```
List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb")
```

Comment: Similar question for arbitrary number of lists: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19097078/770361

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you're looking for is usually called "intersperse" or "intercalate" and there are a few ways to do it:

```
def intersperse[A](a : List[A], b : List[A]): List[A] = a match {
  case first :: rest => first :: intersperse(b, rest)
  case _             => b
}
```

You can also use `scalaz`

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val lst1 = ...
val lst2 = ...

lst1 intercalate lst2
```

**Edit**: You can also do the following:

```
lst1.zipAll(lst2,"","") flatMap { case (a, b) => Seq(a, b) }
```

Come to think of it, I believe the last solution is my favorite since it's most concise while still being clear. If you're already using Scalaz, I'd use the second solution. The first is also very readable however.

And just to make this answer more complete, adding @Travis Brown's solution that is generic:

```
list1.map(List(_)).zipAll(list2.map(List(_)), Nil, Nil).flatMap(Function.tupled(_ ::: _))
```

Comment: Your last solution won't work if the lists aren't the same length—you'd need the much less elegant `list1.map(List(_)).zipAll(list2.map(List(_)), Nil, Nil).flatMap(Function.tupled(_ ::: _))`.

Comment: @yan: 1st solution fails when the first list is empty.

Comment: @TravisBrown fixed the last solution while still being somewhat elegant (although not generic)

Comment: @raHul how? `intersperse(Nil, List(1,2,3))` => `List(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @yan: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list. This is the exception that I got

Comment: What version of Scala? That really shouldn't happen since the first case should not match if the list is empty.

Comment: @raHul I guess you were using my version with empty list check placed as second to get that exception

Comment: I am using Scala 2.9.2

Comment: As @arkonautom said, are you sure you're using the solution I provided?

Comment: it would be interesting to have a solution to interscalate multiple lists

Answer (score 5):

```
val list1 = List("Mary", "a", "lamb")
val list2 = List("had", "little")

def merge1(list1: List[String], list2: List[String]): List[String] = {
    if (list1.isEmpty) list2
    else list1.head :: merge(list2, list1.tail)
}

def merge2(list1: List[String], list2: List[String]): List[String] = list1 match {
    case List() => list2
    case head :: tail => head :: merge(list2, tail)
} 

merge1(list1, list2)
merge2(list1, list2)
//> List[String] = List(Mary, had, a, little, lamb)
```

Comment: This would be much nicer if you matched on the structure of the list rather than using `head` and `tail`.

Comment: ty, added version with matching

Comment: @arkonautom, I don't think that's what Travis Brown had in mind. Check my answer for a match on structure

Comment: @yan yours is better indeed ... almost did it, have a +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.zipAll(list2,"","").flatMap(_.productIterator.toList).filter(_ != "")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def alternate[A]( a: List[A], b: List[A] ): List[A] = {
    def first( a: List[A], b: List[A] ): List[A] = a match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case x :: xs => x :: second( xs, b )
    }

    def second( a: List[A], b: List[A] ): List[A] = b match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case y :: ys => y :: first( a, ys )
    }

    first( a, b )
}
```